# How do I make IntelliJ IDEA aware of the in-memory tables created through an SQL script?

Tags: intellij-idea, h2

This actually works, but IntelliJ IDEA doesn't know that yet. Since the tables are created at runtime (as specified by `schema-h2.sql`), the IDE believes the tables are absent and issues error-level warnings. Can I do something "smarter" than simply disabling the inspection?

[image: table names highlighted in red]

I configured it as an in-memory database

[image: Data Source And Drivers window]

How do I make IntelliJ IDEA aware of the in-memory tables created through an SQL script?